# Updating a pod (cocoapods)?

Tags: objective-c, git, github, terminal, cocoapods

The first version I released for my framework was `1.0.0.`

I just finished version `1.1.0` and wanted to update the the version in cocoa pods.

Steps I did:

1. Updated `podspec` file (Changed the version and `tag` to `1.1.0` and added a framework that I needed).
2. I first pushed the changes to Github using the Github for Mac app
3. Ran `pod lib lint` and passed validation
4. Entered `git add -A && git commit -m "Release 1.1.0"` and got a weird (Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit).
5. Entered `git tag '1.1.0'`
6. Entered `git push --tags` (and it said everything was good and it showed 1.1.0 passing).

When I search my framework in pod search "name" it still shows 1.0.0 as the version.

Did I miss something or does it take some time to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer to cocoapods spec [Cocoa guid](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html)

You can use

```
pod trunk push NAME.podspec
```

Your steps 4,5,6 is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @tdelepine. It just took a bit of time to update itself.

Answer (score 2):

You just follow the below terminal commands.
While your going to update your pods you just focus on the below terminal commands.These commands are more than enough for update your pods. Hope it may help you.

**Open the Terminal:**

```
$sudo gem update —system
$sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
$sudo gem install cocoapods
$pod setup
$cd <project path>
$pod init
$ open -a Xcode Podfile

add files(framework name) into to your pod file.
```

**Example:**

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'
```

Save your pod file. then,

```
$pod install
$pod update(if you need)
```

The frameworks will downloading the latest version, if we are not mentioning the version name (Ex:

> pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'

)

```
platform :ios, '7.0' (The version 7.0 is your Deployment target)
```

Open your project folder --> Open the **project workspace** not the Xcode project.

Clean the Project.

Run the Project.

Hope it will useful for you.!

Thanks.